# sed combination of two commands, is that possible

Tags: macos, sed, terminal

I have two sed commands to delete the occurences of "[" and "]" in a text file only in lines which contain "INSERT INTO" which are doing the job well so far.

```
1 sed "/INSERT INTO/ s/\[//g" < Export.sql     > ExportTemp.sql
2 sed "/INSERT INTO/ s/\]//g" < ExportTemp.sql > ExportSQL.sql
```

Right now I 
1 reads file Export.sql     and writes file ExportTemp.sql and than
2 reads file ExportTemp.sql and writes file ExportSQL.sql which is what I actually want.

I wonder if I can combine those two lines into one?

Any clues?

Comment: you don't need such a big signature block :P

Answer (score 3):

In your case you may not need `sed` multiple commands. What about:

```
sed '/INSERT INTO/ s/[][]//g' Export.sql > ExportSQL.sql
```

Comment: Really great, works like a charm. What I don´t understand why don´t I have to escape the two brackets I want to change?

Comment: You have 2 characters within a character class. Characters classes have a special syntax: regular expression metacharacters are not special in a character class. However, the `]` character needs appear as the first char to distinguish it from the terminating bracket. See http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regular-Expressions

Answer (score -1):

You can have multiple commands per invocation.  See the sed manpage --

http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed